# Reversing a string c without library function results in seqmentation fault

Tags: c

I get segmentation fault whenever i try to run this. Have no idea why. The logic seems to be correct, its probably something with function calls. Debugger says something about stack but i have no idea how to interpretate this.

```
char* rev_string(char* t)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    i = j = 0;
    char tmp;
    while(t[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    while(i > j)
    {
        tmp = t[i];
        t[i] = t[j];
        t[j] = tmp;
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: what is the 'something' that it says?

Comment: did you actually try stepping through with the debugger? Watch i and j

Comment: When the first loop ends, `t[i]` _will_ be equal to zero, so, even if the process succeeds, you'll have a null-terminator at the beginning.

Comment: You need to show a [MCVE].

Comment: And after I got through with adding the boilerplate code this example needs to actually *run*... I -1'ed.

Comment: My guess is you are calling this function on a string literal, but we will never know if you don't show how you're calling it. Also, how about telling us what the debugger actually showed instead of "something about stack"?

Comment: "Program received signal SIGSEGV. Stack Trace is available in the call stack tab" then it points to line 25 (t[i] = t[j]) then again "Program received..." and then it crashes

Comment: char* text = "sampletext";      char* newtext = rev_string(text);

Comment: @JanChabik, well, that's the problem: it's impossible to reverse a string literal because it's impossible to modify it. You should either copy it with `strdup` or allocate memory like `char text[] = "stuff";`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are swapping the first character with the null terminating character at the end of the string, causing the string to be of length 0 since the first character is `\0`. You need to move your `j` marker back by one once you found `\0`.

```
char* rev_string(char* t)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    i = j = 0;
    char tmp;
    while(t[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    i--;
    while(i > j)
    {
        tmp = t[i];
        t[i] = t[j];
        t[j] = tmp;
        i--;
        j++;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: While true, this would not cause a segfault.

Comment: Well the question does state "without library function", so I assume `strlen` would violate rule of not using library functions